# recovering the deleted python script file

Tags: linux, version-control, backup, rm, file-recovery

How can we recover the deleted python script file(deleted using rm), say lostfile.py in debian linux box?
The file system of the linux box is jfs

Comment: Commercial Solution:  http://www.kerneldatarecovery.com/linux-jfs-data-recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not going to help you right now, but the best way would be to redeploy the script from its original source or to restore it from version control or from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I just tried building this and had some compilation issues. If you are going to try this, be sure to successfully building the jfsrec before you do anything else. `dd` on a large filesystem would take a long time. I would hate for this to waste your time, if you can't compile the tool.

Here's an open source tool called [jfsrec](http://jfsrec.sourceforge.net/).

If it were me, I would:

1. boot to live disc of Ubuntu or some other distro
2. `dd` an image of the partition that the .py file existed on (this is in early development, so I wouldn't want to use the tool directly on the filesystem you are interested in)
3. download and compile jfsrec (other dependencies may need to be installed for compiling)
4. mount the `dd` image that you just created
5. run the jfsrec tool on the mounted image

Invocation of jfsrec:

```
./jfsrec --device /mnt/jfspartition --output /mnt/reallybig_hdd/recovered --logdir /mnt/reallybig_hdd/logs --first py
```

More details can be seen at the link provided at the top.